# Qooxdoo Automation

Tags: selenium, automation, qooxdoo

I'm trying to create test automation for a third party but all of the usual routes seem to be unsuccessful. I was hoping that someone had some insight on possible tools and paths I could take. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This tutorial may be valuable for you: https://news.qooxdoo.org/tutorial-automated-ui-testing-with-the-qooxdoo-simulator-35c41ea19cfa#.7jlv3nv3a

Comment: @level420 this is a post from 2011 and does not work.